# Monitoring user behaviour with custom JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

How I do monitor all the clicks and inputs on my page? I would ideally want to make a video of what the user does on my app; the way they uses my app.

How do I go about this?

Any links or demos would be really great.

Edit : What I have in mind is:

1. log all the events into a cookie , and send it to the server in frequent intervals.
2. then startup a Firefox session and trigger these events on the page . and capture it as a video.

Edit: Basically I have an app, and I want to see what the user does on the app, so I will monitor their clicks and inputs (that's pretty much what they do on the click), and then trigger those events back on my web app. So I will pretty be able to replicate their actions on my page. Now the question is, how do I capture all the necessary events, how do I serialize and trigger these events for later?

Comment: Why downvote the question without an explanation? Indeed it might not be totally objective, but I feel it is valid enough.

Comment: I agree, its a valid question, even if a slightly scary one - I think/hope the OP just wants to analyze usage, and doesn't know where to start and assumed this is the way - rather than the more traditional ways.

Comment: Because he's asking for a full featured application here.

Comment: I am not certain this will help (so it is a _comment_ instead of an _answer_), but you might look at how Google Analytics works as a template for what you are trying to accomplish. My (admittedly limited) understanding of Google Analytics suggests that it does something similar to this. I don't know if it is as granular as you want to get, but it might get you to a good start.

Comment: This kind of functionality is very very possible, and is in use all around the web today. See [Clicktale](http://www.clicktale.com)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that you can make a 'video' unless you tracked every single movement of the mouse, which would extremely unfriendly, probably take a lot of processing time and raise ethical questions.

If you want to know how a user interacts with your site so that you can improve it (presumably) then you need to get into web analytics.

There are many options.  My personal favourite is [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics)

Comment: if not every single movement of the mouse , atleast all the clicks and the inputs on the page

Comment: That already exists and has been made. It's a product that competes with crazy egg. Their customer service sucks so I won't mention the product at the risk of promoting their sales.

Comment: A 'vanilla' GA implementation will track page views and visits, but you can use custom events to track how people interact with other parts of the site, such as forms, searches etc.  It can also track goals/funnels and ecommerce, site search, and so, so much more.  But you need to do some coding for many of the advanced features.

Answer (score 2):

With JavaScript you can create what's known as a heatmap of use clicks:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/02/08/a-jquery-heat-map/

You can't capture a video of the users desktop session using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing [ClickHeat](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html) (or a similar variant) a long time ago. Had no experience with it, so I can't help with pros and cons, and it doesn't answer your question entirely (don't think it does keystrokes, although maybe I'm wrong, like I said I don't really know).

Might not be a total solution, but should be a good starting point.

In a similar vein it wouldn't be hard to capture mouse position every so often along with a timestamp and recreate a given user's actions. Generating a general/average movement is much more difficult with this type of data, but it's useful on the single-unit basis. So too with keystrokes, they're all just events.